# Populate drop down list from MySQL column data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am currently having trouble displaying the entries in a column of my database in a drop down list.

The code below... is half working i guess...
When I run it, the drop down list gives me 6 options (the column in my database also has 6 columns) Now I just need to get the names to show up!

All help is appreciated!

```
<select id="teamlist" name="teamlist">
<?php
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=clubresults', 'root', '12345678');
  #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
  $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select teamname from members');
  $stmt->execute();
  while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<option>{$row['teamname']}</option>";
  }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: try var_dump($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) to check your output

Comment: error Unexpected T While

Comment: erm its not coming out anything.. no errors but just no list..|

drop down contains 6 options with no name

Comment: you can try that before while loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 <select id="teamlist" name="teamlist">
 <?php
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=clubresults', 'root', '12345678');
        #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
        $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select teamname from members');
    $stmt->execute();
       while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option>'.$row['teamname'].'</option>';
       }
     ?>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

`{` is not needed inside `<option>`

```
echo "<option>".$row['teamname']."</option>"
```